# Postgres формат даты

Tags: postgresql, дата

В БД формат даты такого вида 2017-02-05
Можно ли поменять формат даты на 05.02.2017 или 05-02-2017
В postgres.conf следующее

```
datestyle = 'german,dmy'
```

Comment: А поменять `datestyle` почему нет?

Comment: на какой? вроде как datestyle = 'german,dmy' и должен подходить

Comment: В БД дата вообще хранится во внутреннем бинарном формате. А её отображение настраивайте уже на уровне клиента как хотите - либо форматируйте в запросе. В любом случае изменение ВИДА - это не сервера забота.

Comment: @Евгений Гусев Не знаю точно, просто подумалось, что `german` это локальный формат, а там ISO. Не имеет значения, т.к. менять не рекомендуется потому, что посыпется всё, что по-умолчанию конвертировалось. Используйте `to_char(...)` где необходимо.